# Looking for special C++ data structure

Tags: c++, data-structures, iterator, complexity-theory

I'm looking for a C++ implementation of a data structure ( or a combination of data structures ) that meet the following criteria:

- **items are accessed in the same way as in std::vector**
- provides random access iterator ( along with iterator comparison <,> )
- average item **access**(:lookup) time is at worst of `O(log(n))` complexity
- items are iterated over in the same order as they were added to the container
- given an iterator, i can find out the ordinal position of the item pointed to in the container, at worst of `O(log(n))` complexity
- provides item insertion and removal **at specific position** of at worst `O(log(n))` complexity
- removal/insertion of items does not invalidate previously obtained iterators

Thank you in advance for any suggestions

Dalibor

(Edit) Answers:

The answer I selected describes a data structure that meet all these requirements. However, boost::multi_index, as suggested by Maxim Yegorushkin, provides features very close to those above.

(Edit) Some of the requirements were not correctly specified. They are modified according to **correction**(:original)

(Edit) I've found an implementation of the data structure described in the accepted answer. So far, it works as expected. It's called [counter tree](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8437476/works/countertree_2.0/doc/index.html)

(Edit) Consider using the AVL-Array suggested by sp2danny

Comment: You can't have multi-line comments. Better to edit the question.

Comment: Perhaps a boost.multi_index with an underlying vector plus a set-type index for fast lookup...

Comment: I've been looking into the STL containers and this is what they lack, in comparison to the list above:

vector:
- insertion/removal of O(n) complexity
- insertion/removal invalidates iterators

list:
- no random access
- item lookup of O(n) complexity
- cannot find out the ordinal position from iterator

set/map:
- do not keep the order of items

various combinations of these solve the problems only partially and tend to introduce other issues. I cannot store the ordinal position anywhere, because insertion/removal would invalidate all these values and rebuilding them would be expensive

Comment: i did not want to put it into the question, cause it might make people start thinking along those same lines

Comment: I'm confident that there is no standard C++ library (STL is assimilated) container that meets all these specs.

Comment: There is no such container that would meet all your requirements in the standard library. 
Also, I don't believe there exists such a container even theoretically. You should prioritize your requirements so that we can think of something most suitable

Comment: your list of requirements precludes the use of any known *single* data structure. The only way you will meet all of them is to use something which combines multiple data structures (such the `boost::multi_index` mentioned by Kerrek)

Comment: By ordinal, do you mean element's order in the sorted set? Are you building a book for level 2 or 3 market data?

Comment: If there were such a container, that would be the only one in the standard library.

Comment: the link to counter-tree is dead

Comment: I've found an alternative link, it should be working now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go through these...

> - average item lookup time is at worst of O(log(n)) complexity
> - removal/insertion of items does not invalidate previously obtained iterators
> - provides item insertion and removal of at worst O(log(n)) complexity

That pretty much screams "tree".

> - provides random access iterator ( along with iterator comparison <,> )
> - given an iterator, i can find out the ordinal position of the item pointed to in the container, at worst of O(log(n)) complexity
> - items are iterated over in the same order as they were added to the container

I'm assuming that the index you're providing your random-access iterator is by order of insertion, so `[0]` would be the oldest element in the container, `[1]` would be the next oldest, etc. This means that, on deletion, for the iterators to be valid, the iterator internally cannot store the index, since it could change without notice. So just using a `map` with the key being the insertion order isn't going to work.

Given that, each node of your tree needs to keep track of how many elements are in each subtree, in addition to its usual members. This will allow random-access with `O(log(N))` time. I don't know of a ready-to-go set of code, but subclassing `std::rb_tree` and `std::rb_node` would be my starting point.

Comment: This is exactly of what I was thinking of, but I did not know any existing implementation.

Comment: That's why I said you'd probably have to roll your own starting with the standard library red-black tree code.

Comment: Never heard that the standard library had `rb_tree` and `rb_node`?

Comment: rb_tree and rb_node are not documented because they are implementation details (used internally) of the provided STL containers.

Answer (score 4):

Based on your requirements `boost::multi_index` with two indices does the trick.

The first index is [ordered index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/ord_indices.html). It allows for O(log(n)) insert/lookup/remove. The second index is [random access index](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/rnd_indices.html). It allows for random access and the elements are stored in the order of insertion. For both indices iterators don't get invalidated when other elements are removed. Converting from one iterator to another is O(1) operation.

Comment: I guess you have to be careful to track which iterator you have. Also, is iterating over all the items in order `O(N)` or `O(N*log(N))`? I.e. is the iterator's `operator++` `O(1)` or `O(log(N))`?

Comment: The doc for ordered index does not state the complexity of `operator++`. However, it is implemented as red-black tree, so the complexity of iterator's `operator++` is the same as that of `std::set` or `std::map`. Namely O(1).

Comment: complexity of iterating over all the items is not important. I think I was unclear in the provided specification. I need to access the items only by the order of their insertion. I have nothing else to order them by (that would be of use), so I think that disqualifies the ordered index of boost::multi_index. Random access index seems to almost do the trick, except inserting/deleting elements at any place other than the end of the sequence has O(log(n)) complexity

Comment: @Dalibor: looks like you are not familiar with `boost::multi_index`. I suggest you read the [Tutorial](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_index/doc/tutorial/index.html) and then re-read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

See here: [STL Containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) (scroll down the page to see information on algorithmic complexity) and I think [`std::deque`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/deque/) fits your requirements.

Comment: How does `deque` allow for fast look-up by value? Also, container modification *does* invalidate iterators (but not *references* to elements).

Comment: `deque` is worst-case `O(N)` lookup and removal, IIRC.

Comment: I don't think a `deque` satisfies the insertion/removal constraints (except for insertions/removals at the front and end). See 23.3.3.4 in  n3290.pdf C++0x preliminary standard.

Comment: for a `deque` insertion and removal may not have `O(log(n))` time complexity

Comment: @Aditya: Correct. Insertion and/or removal should be `O(1)` from either end or `O(N)` anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

[AVL-Array](http://avl-array.sourceforge.net/) should fit the bill.

Comment: Don't know why this has been down-voted. The referenced data structure, according to the documentation, satisfies the requirements. Only thing I'm missing is the ability to tell the ordinal position of an object in the array given its iterator. I may have overlooked something in the documentation?

Comment: ordinal position from iterator is missing from the source. I needed it myself, and added it as a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my "lv" container that fit the requirement, O(log n) insert/delete/access time.
   https://github.com/xhawk18/lv

The container is header only C++ libraries,
and has the same iterator and functions with other C++ containers, such as list and vector.

"lv" container is based on rb-tree, each node of which has a size value about the amount of nodes in the sub-tree. By check the size of left/right child of a tree, we can fast access the node randomly.

Comment: Thanks. How does it compare to the counter_tree and AVL-array mentioned in the question edits?

Comment: Hi, Dalibor, It's an implement of counter tree, with rb-tree as the base data structure.